# Rogue X session bombing my CPU

Tags: linux, xorg, process, gdm

Every time I boot I get the following process that is taking %99.3 of my CPU

```
/usr/bin/X :0 -nr -verbose -auth /var/run/gdm/auth-for-gdm-EowSOU/database -nolisten tcp vt7
```

when I kill the pid I lose ssh connection, apache goes down and have to restart the machine.

Anyone know what this is?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

just change the file mode for /etc/init.d/gdm to 644.

```
   sudo chmod 644 /etc/init.d/gdm
```

to return /etc/init.d/gdm to its original mode set 655, (or check before setting). Be warned it might disable graphics login.

Answer (score 0):

This is your X Server, the base for all of your GUI.  Killing X will kill your terminals, which kills your shells, which will kill most of the things running from your shells.

This shouldn't kill apache though, because it is normally run in a way that killing the shell that runs it won't kill it.  It's a special type of process known as a [daemon](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Daemon_(computer_software)) (pronounced demon)

So, you now have a followup question, possibly two.  One is, why is your XServer taking up so much CPU. The other, why is apache dying when your terminal closes.

Comment: thanks for the response. Thats why this is so puzzling. I know that killing this process should not bring down the system. I do have a virtual X session that i log into from VNC from time to time but that is running on its own PID.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing gdm, xorg and xserver and it fixed (removed) the bad process.

Maybe a hack fix but I don't use the GUI anyways and it could always be reinstalled...

Comment: you should accept an answer (preferably mine of course ;) ) to close your question out.